# app that uses linkedin API log in with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, linkedin-api

[image]

I'm creating an app that uses linkedin API log in  with Flutter I have used https://pub.dev/packages/linkedin_login/example for my app and this is what happened; can anyone please help me?

I changed the redirect URLs and it did not work; I don't have a lot of experience with Flutter nor API,
or if there is any source you think will be helpful let me know.